# C program to calculate Binomial Coefficient with factorial method

Tags: c, math, calculator, binomial-coefficients

I'm pretty sure it's only a small mistake but I don't know why it is not working..?

I would really appreciate if you could help me out!

```
#include <stdio.h>

int fak(int n) {
    int fak_n;
    if (n <= 1) {
        fak_n = 1;
    }
    for (int i = 2; i <= n; i++) {
        fak_n = fak_n * i;
    }
    return fak_n;
}

int bin(int n, int k) {
    return fak(n) / (fak(k) * fak(n - k));
}
        
int main() {
    int n;
    int k;
    scanf("%d%d", &n, &k);
    printf("%d\n", bin(n, k));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You might consider "long int" or so instead of simple "int": you might fall into overflow related issues.

Answer (score 2):

`fak_n` is used without initialization when `n` is larger than 1. The initialization should be done unconditionally like this:

```
int fak(int n) {
    int fak_n=1;
    for(int i=2; i<=n; i++){
        fak_n=fak_n*i;
    }
    return fak_n;
}
```

Comment: thanks so much! so it really was just a tiny mistake, thanks!

Comment: @user15991497 If this answered your question, you should consider marking it as "accepted".

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 problems in your code:

- `fak_n` is not initialized in the `fak()` function. You should write:

  ```
    int fak(int n) {
        int fak_n = 1;
        for (int i = 2; i <= n; i++) {
            fak_n = fak_n * i;
        }
        return fak_n;
    }
  ```
- type `int` has a limited range, typically 31 bits, so it can only represent factorials up to `fak(12)`, so computing `bin(13,1)` which is `13`, will cause an arithmetic overflow and produce an incorrect value. You should use a larger type such as `unsigned long long` and use a different formula.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>

unsigned long long fak(int n) {
    unsigned long long fak_n = 1;
    for (int i = 2; i <= n; i++) {
        fak_n = fak_n * i;
    }
    return fak_n;
}

unsigned long long bin(int n, int k) {
    // check definition domain
    if (k < 0 || k > n || n < 0)
        return 0;
    // use factorials for small values
    if (n <= 20)
        return fak(n) / fak(k) / fak(n - k);
    // use Pascal triangle for larger ones
    return bin(n - 1, k - 1) + bin(n - 1, k);
}
        
int main() {
    int n, k;
    if (scanf("%d%d", &n, &k) == 2) {
        printf("%lld\n", bin(n, k));
    }
    return 0;
}
```